# Sharing DB transactions between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, oracle, entity-framework

I have .net3.5 C# application.

The application uses EntityFramework as its DB interface.

This applications calls c++ unmanaged dll which uses the DB as well. This dll updates the DB.

I want to be able to rollback. I want this operation to include the changes done by the main application and the changes done by the dll.

How can I do so? Can I share the same db connection with the dll? Can I share the transaction with the dll?

Thanks,

Mattan

Answer (score 0):

With the Entity Framework, you can provide your own `SqlConnection` instance. You can then use this instance to start transactions with. This gives you control over the database connection, which is a start.

Concerning the unmanaged code, I would suggest that you would allow an entry point from the DLL into your managed code which allows it to execute SQL on this `SqlConnection`.

Because the `SqlConnection` class is written entirely in managed code, it is not possible to pass the actual connection handle to unmanaged code and allow the normal unmanaged functions to use this connection. Because you have the Entity Framework as starting point, you will need the `SqlConnection`, so letting the DLL send SQL statements to the managed connect will probably be the only way.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to share the DB connection?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the managed connection isn't just wrapping an unmanaged MSSQL connection library: it's a fully managed implementation. This means that there is not "raw unmanaged handle" to get. This means that you're working with two totally separated implementations: a managed and an unmanaged. Thus, you have to choose one and route all commands through that connection. And since I can't imagine the entity framework to work with a wrapper to the unmanaged version, I'd try going the other way as described in the answer.